# Strdup fails using it with multiple elements in char**

Tags: c++

I have the following code -

```
char* get_conn(void);

void main(void){
 char** data= new char*[2];
 data=get_conn();

 char* name;
 char* ip;

 name=strdup(data[0]);
 ip=strdup(data[1]);
}

char** get_conn(){
 char* mistring[2];
 mystring[0]="One thing";
 mystring[1]="another thing";
 return(mistring);
}
```

In which `get_conn` returns a `char**` that was originally `char* mistring[2]`.
The thing is, when I debug it, 'name' is copied just fine but in 'ip' I don't get what was stored in data[1].

If I change the order like this,

```
ip=strdup(data[1]);
name=strdup(data[0]);
```

Now ip is copied right and name isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show definition of `get_conn`. You are probably returning pointer to local data.

Comment: The first line allocates memory and stores a pointer to the allocated memory in `data`. The second line overwrites that pointer. That's a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char** data= new char*[2];
data=get_conn();
```

Here, you have *[memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)*. You allocate `data` but immediately it gets overwritten with the value returned from `get_conn()`.

Another problem is you are returning a local variable. `mystring` is a local array whose lifetime is only its enclosing block (i.e. `get_conn()` function here). So you can't return it. This leads to [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can do the allocation in `get_conn()` itself and return it:

```
const char** get_conn(void);

int main(void){
 const char** data;
 data=get_conn();

 ....
}

const char** get_conn(){
 const char **mystring = new const char*[2];

 mystring[0]="One thing";
 mystring[1]="another thing";

 return(mystring);
}
```